# how to make single installer for the two applications(exe and msi)?

Tags: windows-installer

I seen many samples which will run both the installer independently...But in my installer it will allow the first exe to be run, if any error occurs it has to rollback..if it is succeeded it has to install second msi app.

I tried with wix but it feels tough...

Comment: Are both of these apps "yours"? Or are they third-party? If one of them is and one of them isn't, which are you trying to call which? I think there may be a way forward here but you need to give us more details.

Comment: both apps are from thrid party....I have my own application but if i want to run my app, i have to install two third party application to the system. But the end user have to feel it is a single installation.At least after the first app installation i have to continue the second..The user never want to intall both app at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I have two ideas. Even as I'm thinking about them, I'm thinking "there's got to be a better way" but maybe they'll sow some seeds for you so you can work out how to do it properly.

Idea One, can you check whether the two third-party apps that you wish to install are available as merge modules? If so, then you could maybe incorporate them into your own setup program?

Idea Two, on the assumption that life isn't that straightforward, in your own setup program you could create a custom action dll. Within that dll, you could write code that kicks off the setup process for the third-party app? I'm certain that you could construct your custom action such that you could spawn a process, wait for it to complete, and interrogate its exit code. So in that respect you could know success/failure and commit/rollback accordingly. But I'm not even sure that this approach would work (two setup programs running concurrently sounds like it could be problematic).

For what its worth...

Answer (score 0):

If you familiar with Windows Installer technology, I recommend create own installer and include these 3rd party apps as prerequisites. Create custom actions which allow you to control installation process.  Also you can't install one MSI from another (exclusion is chained MSI, but it more complex for this task). 
Also if WiX is not requirement, could try to do it with help of AdvancedInstaller, it easier to create installers then WiX and they have free version as well.